# Should Kernel size be same as word size in 1D Convolution?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, word-embedding

In CNN literature, it is often illustrated that  kernel size is same as size of the longest word in the vocabulary list that one has, when it sweeps across a sentence.

So if we use embedding to represent the text, then shouldn't the kernel size be same as the embedding dimension so that it gives the same effect as sweeping word by word?

I see difference sizes of kernel used, despite the word length.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... these are 1D convolutions, for which the kernels are 3 dimensional.

It's true that one of these 3 dimensions must match the embedding size (otherwise it would be pointless to have this size)

These three dimensions are:

```
(length_or_size, input_channels, output_channels)
```

Where:

- `length_or_size` (`kernel_size`): anything you want. In the picture, there are 6 different filters with sizes 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, represented by the "vertical" dimension.
- `input_channels` (automatically the `embedding_size`): the size of the embedding - this is somwehat mandatory (in Keras this is automatic and almost invisible), otherwise the multiplications wouldn't use the entire embedding, which is pointless. In the picture, the "horizontal" dimension of the filters is constantly 5 (the same as the word size - this is not a spatial dimension).
- `output_channels` (`filters`): anything you want, but it seems the picture is talking about 1 channel only per filter, since it's totally ignored, and if represented would be something like "depth".

So, you're probably confusing which dimensions are which. When you define a conv layer, you do:

```
Conv1D(filters = output_channels, kernel_size=length_or_size)
```

While the `input_channels` come from the embedding (or the previous layer) automatically.

### Creating this model in Keras

To create this model, it would be something like:

```
sentence_length = 7
embedding_size=5

inputs = Input((sentence_length,))
out = Embedding(total_words_in_dic, embedding_size)
```

Now, supposing these filters have 1 channel only (since the image doesn't seem to consider their depth...), we can join them in pairs of 2 channels:

```
size1 = 4
size2 = 3
size3 = 2
output_channels=2

out1 = Conv1D(output_channels, size1, activation=activation_function)(out)
out2 = Conv1D(output_channels, size2, activation=activation_function)(out)
out3 = Conv1D(output_channels, size3, activation=activation_function)(out)
```

Now, let's collapse the spatial dimensions and remain with the two channels:

```
out1 = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(out1)
out2 = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(out2)
out3 = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(out3)
```

And create the 6 channel output:

```
out = Concatenate()([out1,out2,out3])
```

Now there is a mistery jump from 6 channels to 2 channels which cannot be explained by the picture. Perhaps they're applying a Dense layer or something.......

```
#????????????????
out = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(out)

model = Model(inputs, out)
```

Comment: Ok, I should have worded better. I wasn't really interested in the image. I just used it for illustration.

Here is conv1D from Keras:

keras.layers.Conv1D(filters, kernel_size, .........)

Here is Embedding layer from Keras:

keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim, output_dim,.....)

What I wanted to know is if 'output_dim'  ( I call it embedding dimension) and 'kernel_size' need to be the same size?

Comment: No, the filters will have these dimensions: `(kernel_size, automatic_embedding_size, filters)`, where `automatic_embedding_size==input_channels`.

Comment: That is what confused me. We like to talk about how the sliding window (kernel width) should cover a full word (in the illustration), but when we represent word as embedding, the sliding window doesn't need to cover the embedding width that corresponds to a full word.

Comment: In a 1D convolution, it's not "kernel width", it's "input_channels", in the sense that it's not a spatial dimension, but a number of "features". There isn't any sliding in this dimension (it's not useful to slide the embedding size, there isn't any spatial relation between its weights).

Comment: Actually there is kernel width. The second argument 'kernel_size' defines the length/width of the sliding window. I am pretty sure 'input_channels' is the first argument 'feature'. Look up the Conv1D on Keras site.

Comment: No, it's all explained in the answer, there are 3 dimensions in the kernel. (kernel_size, input_channels, features). You only define 2 of them because the other is automatic. This automatic one is the one you're talking about (you can't change the input size, it's defined by the previous layer, and it's the embedding size). The other two are totally free to choose.

Comment: Man, that is super confusing as hell the way Keras describe:
"kernel_size: An integer or tuple/list of a single integer, specifying the length of the 1D convolution window." But yeah, I guess I should do further digging. Thanks!

Comment: Yes... it's confusing because Keras never mentions the third dimension of the kernel (probably because it was made to be simple and easy). This `kernel_size` you define (among the 3 dimensions) is the only spatial dimension that exists, and also the only sliding direction, that's why it's a 1D convolution, it refers to the "sentence length". --- If you go to 2D convolutions, then you will start having width and height as kernel sizes (2 spatial dimensions), plus the output filters, plus the never mentioned input channels, making a 4D kernel.

Comment: You should write a  book on Keras framework about all the potential pitfalls and confusions, with easily understandable illustrations, and sell it online. I would buy in a heartbeat. That's gonna save countless hours and costly design mistakes for lots of people, man.

Comment: I'm seriously considering that. And more people are telling me this....